# How to make a function execute only after certain function completes?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, flotr

```
Event.observe(document, 'dom:loaded', function() {

    new Ajax.Request('/HumblFin/Serv', {
        method:'get',
        onSuccess: function(transport){
            var data = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
            drawChart(data);
        },
        onFailure: function(){ alert('Something went wrong...') }
    });


function drawChart(data)
{

     for (var i = 0; i < data.jobs.length; i++)  { 
         priceData.push([i, data.jobs[i].INCPU]);
         dateData.push(data.jobs[i].Dater);

        }
}
```

Hereafter completion of the `drawchart(data)` method only I want to execute the below code 
but unfortunately the function `HumbleFinance.init` is being called with empty data.

Please tell me how to solve this.
I can't put the below code inside the drawChart(data) function

```
HumbleFinance.init('finance', priceData , dateData);
Event.observe(HumbleFinance.containers.summary, 'flotr:select', function (e) {

    var area = e.memo[0];
    xmin = Math.floor(area.x1);
    xmax = Math.ceil(area.x2);

    var date1 = dateData[xmin];
    var date2 = dateData[xmax];

    $('dateRange').update(dateData[xmin] + ' - ' + dateData[xmax]);

});
});
```

Comment: Put it in the `onSuccess` function.

Comment: One side note: you know you're creating global variables in the second code snippet (`xmin` and `xmax`), don't you?

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `HumbleFinance.init()` is happening before you get your ajax response and process the data results.  You need to make sure you process your ajax response before you call this `init`.  To do that, you just move the `init` call to within the `onSuccess` callback, after the `drawChart` method call.

```
<script>
Event.observe(document, 'dom:loaded', function() {

    new Ajax.Request('/HumblFin/Serv', {
        method:'get',
        onSuccess: function(transport){
            var data = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
            drawChart(data);

            //Put your HumbleFinance.init call here, 
            //after the priceData and dateData has been generated.
            HumbleFinance.init('finance', priceData , dateData);
        },
        onFailure: function(){ alert('Something went wrong...') }
    });

    Event.observe(HumbleFinance.containers.summary, 'flotr:select', function (e) {

        var area = e.memo[0];
        xmin = Math.floor(area.x1);
        xmax = Math.ceil(area.x2);

        var date1 = dateData[xmin];
        var date2 = dateData[xmax];

        $('dateRange').update(dateData[xmin] + ' - ' + dateData[xmax]);

    });
});
```